# How to select all different rows which have same more than one value in some column

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have table - MovieCategoty which holds movieId and categoryId as columns,
I need to get all movieId who related to another movieId.
related means - if they have at least two  CategoryID in common.
(the query supposed to be written in MS SQL server).
I have tried few ways but did not get the correct results.

The table is
**MovieCategoty**

| movieId | CategoryId |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 4 |
| 2 | 6 |
| 2 | 4 |
| 3 | 1 |
| 3 | 3 |
| 3 | 6 |
| 4 | 1 |
| 4 | 3 |
| 5 | 1 |
| 5 | 2 |
| 5 | 3 |

For example my query needs to show movieId 3,4 because they both related to 1,3 CategoryId

Comment: Have you tried anything?  If so, you should include it in the question.

Comment: *" have tried few ways but did not get the correct results."* And what *were* those attempts? Include the, in your question. Explain why they didn't work.

Comment: sorry, I am new to this,
I tried few solutions but stop in the half way because I saw that is not the right direction for solving it, next time I will show more information, thanks for the Answer!

Comment: But movieid 5 is also related to 1 and 3

Answer (score 0):

This is a self join with aggregation:

```
select mc1.movieid, mc2.movieid, count(*) as num_categories
from movieCategory mc1 join
     movieCategory mc2
     on mc1.categoryid = mc2.categoryid
group by mc1.movieid, mc2.movieid
having count(*) >= 2;
```

This returns a movie (with two categories) as matching itself.  I'll let you filter that out.  In addition, movie pairs appear twice -- in either direction.

Comment: This solution doesn’t  give the correct result, it just gives movieId that appear at least 2 times, I need to show all “related” movieIds, which means ids who have 2 or more categories in common

Comment: @AlmogL . . . This should be giving pairs of movie ids that have two categories.  A given movie is paired with itself if it has two or more categories.